# Using app.set to set trust proxy

Tags: express, proxy

When setting the application variable `trust proxy`, does the second argument in `app.set` mean that the server trusts all the requests FROM 127.0.0.1 or TO 127.0.0.1?

For example:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');

// or
app.set('trust proxy', '127.0.0.1');
```

and then

```
var sess = {
    proxy: true
     cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true
    }
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html), several types of value are allowed as the second argument:

> #### Boolean
>
> If true, the client’s IP address is understood as the left-most entry
>   in the X-Forwarded-* header.
>
> If false, the app is understood as directly facing the Internet and
>   the client’s IP address is derived from req.connection.remoteAddress.
>   This is the default setting.
>
> #### IP addresses
>
> An IP address, subnet, or an array of IP addresses and subnets to
>   trust. The following list shows the pre-configured subnet names

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this would be for inbound requests (i.e., *from* 127.0.0.1).

The documentation you linked to is talking about running an Express app behind a proxy. When the requests hit the proxy, the proxy routs the requests to the app, and the app sees the proxy's IP address instead of the original client's IP address.

Setting `trust proxy` fixes that problem by ignoring the proxy's IP address (in one way or another), as the documentation explains.

Comment: thanks! I wasn't sure how will I need to adjust my express configuration when going to production. But your explanation really cleared it up for me.