# "c8ycli server" returns an error when try to connect behind the proxy

Tags: proxy, cumulocity

I need to use cumulocity behind the proxy server. Therefore, I have set the proxy addresses using: "npm set proxy" and "npm set https-proxy". Now I am able to run a standard angular project and it works fine.

But when I create a c8y project and run it using "c8ycli server -u ...", I get this error by each request:

[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /tenant/loginOptions from localhost:9000 to https://....com (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

Does c8ycli use npm proxy settings? How can I set proxy address for c8ycli?

Answer (score 1):

I think it has nothing to do with c8y itself. You should try setting the proxy manually with npm:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Taken from [here](https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/)

Hope this help!

Edit:

Checking at the c8y tool (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cumulocity-tools in my case) I notice they are using express (lib/devserver/server.js) when you run the server command. In that file they use their  own proxy (lib/devserver/proxy.js) settings to resolve the localhost to the tenant's url.

As they are using express I think you can change those file to set you proxy configurations. I have not much experience with express but I found some information searching

[express behind-proxies](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html)

[nodejs-express-why-should-i-use-app-enabletrust-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930070/nodejs-express-why-should-i-use-app-enabletrust-proxy)

[using-app-set-to-set-trust-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137873/using-app-set-to-set-trust-proxy)

Good luck!

Comment: As I wrote, I had set the configs and it works fine with standard angular commands. But c8ycli doesn't take these proxy settings and I cannot run c8y projects!

Comment: Your edit addresses  the issue, but how can we adjust the proxy settings for c8y? It would be ideal if  someone from from c8y team suggest a tested solution.